# How to track memory and performance with Chrome

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, memory-management, webgl, pixi.js

I have more of a general question about Chrome and how to debug/troubleshoot memory and performance problems running a PixiJS-backed WebGL + React application in a specific use case.

I have an end user with a number of tabs open in their Chrome instance (Mac M1 laptop). The app often runs too slowly to be usable on this specific computer. If they close Chrome and open Firefox, however, the application runs about as fast as I would expect it to run. The application also runs fine in my testing with one tab open in Chrome.

Overall, I'm trying to figure out where even to start to get a hold on what is causing this specific issue with this specific use case. Developer Tools return a lot of potentially useful debugging information but one problem is that there is too much of it to sort through in a way that I can process sensibly.

Is there a way to determine how much free memory Chrome can access, so that I can make a reasonable heuristic estimate as to whether the app will run decently fast or need to issue a warning to an end user that they need to reduce open tabs or otherwise purge cache or free memory, however that can be done in Chrome?